# Declare array into searchFields Worklight JSONStore

Tags: arrays, search, field, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have a JSON object to my collection with JSONStore like this:

```
{
    name : 'name1',
    industry : ['Banking', 'Energy', 'Insurance', 'Media', 'Retail', 'Telco', 'Travel'],
    buyer : ['CMO'],
    link : 'foo.com' 
}
```

But, how is possible declare the industry field into searchFields?, in order to search a pattern in the array.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

There's no `array` type for search fields. You can only index values in objects that are `string`, `boolean`, `number` and `integer`.

You could change:

```
{ industry : ['Banking', 'Energy'] }
```

to:

```
{ industry : [{name: 'Banking'}, {name: 'Energy'}] }
```

and then use the following search field: `{'industry.name' : 'string'}`. That will enable you to do something like `WL.JSONStore.get('collection').find({'industry.name' : 'Banking'}, {exact: true})` and get back an object like this one:

```
[{_id: ..., json: {name: ..., industry: [..., {name: Banking}, ...], buyer: ..., link: ...}}]
```

This is documented under the search field section of general terminology in the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_terminology.html).

That would mean writing code like this to change the data being added to the collection:

```
var output = [];
['Banking', 'Energy', 'Insurance', 'Media'].forEach(function (element) {
    output.push({name: element});
});
console.log( JSON.stringify(output, null, ' ') );
```

Alternatively, you could also change it into a string:

```
{industry : ['Banking', 'Energy', 'Insurance', 'Media'].toString() }
```

and get back something like this:

```
{industry : "Banking,Energy,Insurance,Media"}
```

Then you can use the search field `{industry : 'string'}` and do something like `WL.JSONStore.get('collection').find({industry: 'Energy'}, {exact: false})` to get objects that have `Energy` somewhere in the `industry` value string.

FYI - Feature requests [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).